# Javascript setInterval not working after closure of a modal popup

Tags: javascript, timer

I am showing a timer on a bootstrap modal popup. I am using setInterval to start a timer. It is working fine for the first time but after the closure of popup and when I open the popup again, timer doesn't show up.

https://jsfiddle.net/8h49o7Lg/

code

```
var timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);

var sec = 00;
    var min = 00;
    function clock() {
        sec += 1;
        if (sec == 60) {
            min += 1;
            sec = 00;
        }
        document.getElementById("timerid").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: It is likely the way you open  /event handler so please show that part

Comment: Do you use `clearInterval()` on hidden.bs.modal event.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8h49o7Lg/ - here is the code

Comment: Your `timer` is local to the function it is in

Answer (score 1):

Oh that's really simple, you just create a new timer every time you open the popup, but you don't get rid of the old one.

I think the simplest solution would be to just clear it the moment you try to assign it again.

```
var timer;
function showtimer(){
      if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
      timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);

      var sec = 00;
      var min = 00;
      function clock() {
          sec += 1;
          if (sec == 60) {
              min += 1;
              sec = 00;
          }
          document.getElementById("timerid").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you do not clear the timer since it was local to the showTimer

Here is a better solution where I also reset the timer display and pad the numbers

```js
let timer;

function showtimer() {
  timer = setInterval(clock, 1000);

  var sec = 00;
  var min = 00;

  function clock() {
    sec += 1;
    if (sec == 60) {
      min += 1;
      sec = 00;
    }
    document.getElementById("timerid").innerHTML = String(min).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(sec).padStart(2, "0");
  }
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '#myModal', function(event) {
  clearInterval(timer); 
  document.getElementById("timerid").innerHTML = "00:00";
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="showtimer()">Open Modal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="timerid">00:00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```